# Name of elementary OS terminal (to open new terminal window from within Terminal)

Tags: pantheon-terminal, command-line

Looking for the command to open a new terminal instance and suggestions I've found to use `terminal` or `gnome-terminal` are incorrect

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but the approved answer is now incorrect and this is still the top Google link for this question, so in new versions of Elementary OS, the terminal is called `io.elementary.terminal`

Comment: It's still working for me on Loki with everything updated right now. How that?

Comment: @EricG What version of Loki? I manually run `sudo apt upgrade` so maybe I'm ahead of what AppCentre is updating people to? `pantheon-terminal` is no longer recognized on my system

Comment: I did a upgrade before commenting and another one right now. Still oantheon-terminal works, the other command doesn't....

Comment: I can also assure you that as of writing `pantheon-terminal` is still working.

Comment: this is nice, how do I pass commands?

Comment: For fish terminal users, need run `$ /usr/bin/bash -c 'io.elementary.terminal -n'` to work openning window properly.

Answer (score 6):

The command to run is:

### `pantheon-terminal`

Comment: This no longer works: `pantheon-terminal: command not found`

Comment: This still works on loki

Comment: `io.elementary.terminal` ?

Answer (score 4):

For the new version elementary 5.1 Hera the correct command to launch a termianl is

```
io.elementary.terminal -n
```

Comment: For fish terminal users, need run `$ /usr/bin/bash -c 'io.elementary.terminal -n'` to work properly.